# Reference a function in a class

Tags: c#

I want to create a class with references to functions to run.
Example code which does not create a reference but runs the function upon creation

```
public class Jobs
{
    public List<Job> jobs;

    public Jobs()
    {
        jobs = new List<Job>()
        {
            new Job()
            {
                name = "Job 1",
                job =  func1() // This runs the function, how do I create a reference to run it later in RunJobs?
            },
            new Job()
            {
                name = "Job 2",
                job =  func1()
            }
        };

    }
    

    private async Task func1()
    {
        // do some stuff    
    }
    private async Task func2()
    {
        // do some other stuff    
    }

    public void RunJobs()
    {
        foreach(Job job in jobs) // Iterating through jobs
        {
            Console.WriteLine(job.name);
            job.job(); // I want to run the referenced function here
        }
    }

}

public class Job
{
    public string name;        
    public Task job; 

}
```

How can I reference func1() and func2() and run them by calling a method in the class when iterating through Jobs.

Comment: The c# term you are looking for is [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

Comment: `jobs = new List<Func<Task>>() { new Job { name = "Job 1", job = () => func1() }, ...};` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) to your object to be invoked at a later time. C# provides some [generic delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0) you can use:

```
public class Job
{
    public string name;        
    public Func<Task> job; 
}
...
new Job()
{
      name = "Job 2",
      job =  func1
}

...
foreach(Job job in jobs) // Iterating through jobs
{
     Console.WriteLine(job.name);
     var myTask = job.job(); // I want to run the referenced function here
}
```

Comment: I think you need to do ``await job.job()``;

Comment: since he named the variable `myTask`, it's fine without the `await`...otherwise he'd assign `void` to the variable, which isn't possible

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad Not necessarily, you *can* await the task, but really depends on what you want to do with it. You could for example add it to a list to await all of the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what your expecting!

```
public class Jobs
{
    public List<Job> jobs;

    public Jobs()
    {
        jobs = new List<Job>()
        {
            new Job()
            {
                name = "Job 1",
                job = func1
            },
            new Job()
            {
                name = "Job 2",
                job =  func2
            }
        };

    }


    private async Task func1()
    {
        // do some stuff    
    }
    private async Task func2()
    {
        // do some other stuff    
    }

    public void RunJobs()
    {
        foreach (Job job in jobs) // Iterating through jobs
        {
            Console.WriteLine(job.name);
            job.job(); // I want to run the referenced function here
        }
    }

}

public class Job
{
    public string name;
    public delegate Task _job();
    public _job job;
}
```